# IdeaVIM colon commands don't execute on enter

Tags: android-studio, ideavim

I just downloaded IdeaVIM for Android Studio.  I type `:` and it brings me to the colon command input, but when I press Enter nothing happens and the cursor stays at the input, not executing the command.

Comment: Are there any exceptions related to key handling in your idea.log ("Help | Shlow Log in ...")?

Comment: I restarted AS and it's working now.  Thanks for the help.